# android/eclipse isn't open

Tags: java, android, eclipse

android/eclipse isn't open when is click on `eclipse.exe`. I downloaded the full android SDK from its site and the file or package name is `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64.zip`. When the file is extracted there are two folders (eclipse and sdk with sdk manager). When I open eclipse it shows a java error (`A java Runtime environment(JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available inorder to run Eclipse. No java virual machine was found after searching the following locations: F"\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH`)
but a another eclipse(juno) doesn't show the error it run easily. I uninstalled the java and reinstall it but still same and also uninstall the previous android sdk manager from c drive (c:) but still same problem appear. Please give me the solution for it so I can develop the apps.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the JAVA_HOME environment variable (Control Panel->System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables...):

JAVA_HOME - c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_06 (change properly if your JDK is located on different place)

You can also define the JVM in your Eclipse folder in eclipse.ini file:
-vm
c:/jre/bin/javaw.exe See: wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: add variable with name "JAVA_HOME" and value with path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25"

Comment: You can also define the JVM in your Eclipse folder in eclipse.ini file:
-vm

c:/jre/bin/javaw.exe

See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert no will I pretend to be. I've had the same problem and have been struggling to find a solution for hours. 
You can't define the JVM in your Eclipse folder in eclipse.ini file if Java Development Kit is not installed so let's assume you have not installed JDK.

I simply downloaded and installed the Java Development Kit from Oracle's website and voila, it worked and it totally ignored the eclipse.ini file (so assume it did but this is what I put in it: "**-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw**" - no quotes). I really don't think it's necessary to even have anything in that file because I've removed EVERYTHING afterwards and it still worked.

Here is the link to download: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

I hope I at least helped one person. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and solved it by downloading Eclipse Classic from its official site, then download and install Android SDK from ([here](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r21.0.1-windows.exe)) and then just follow the tutorial for installing the ADT Plugin on Android Dev ([here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)).

The SDK instalation should find JDK automaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location of jdk for eclipse to find it. From your eclipse directory, run this command: eclipse -vm C:\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\bin\javaw
My version of jdk is 1.7.0_11. You specify your version in the above command.

Answer (score 0):

This actually happened to me. I solved this by doing this.

1. Download a JRE 32 bit version
2. Installed it in the relevant path
   (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\jre)

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was unistall the Java (JDK) version I had and downloaded the last version at the web of Oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. Only with this Eclipse stopped giving that error to me and it works good